# How do I unlock the missing cheat and skater in Tony Hawk Pro Skater 2?

Tags: pc, tony-hawks-pro-skater-2

I have a Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 2 PC career which I think is completely finished. However, the game shows me otherwise. In the CHEATS menu, there is still one cheat shown as ??? (the second-last, between "moon physics" and "level flip" and one skater head is shown with a ? (the one between Officer Dick and Spiderman).

What are these and how do I unlock them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/199061-tony-hawks-pro-skater-2/faqs/9219) has a complete list, (search for "cheats") but they're not in the same order as on the menu, so I can't verify that the ones I've picked out are correct.  That said, I'll take a crack.

To use the cheat codes, start a career mode level and pause, and then **hold Numpad <kbd>7</kbd>** while you enter the code.  More codes *for PC* are [here](http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/thps2.html#.Tu6Z03NOmKM).

The cheat might be Double Moon Physics (seems like that should come after Moon Physics, yeah?):

> [Left], [Up], [Left], [Up], [Down], [Up], C, V, [Left], [Up], [Left], [Up], [Down], [Up], C, V.

The character might be Private Carrera:

> Get all gaps in the game for the non-secret skate parks. It's tough.

Or cheat:

> [Down], [Up], [Left], [Left], B, [Left], [Up], V, V, [Up], [Right], C, C, [Up], [Spacebar]

Comment: OP edit makes this answer .. not so good

Comment: *sigh*.  Thanks for the comment so I have a chance to edit.

Comment: You are right, these are the missing bonuses. Do you know how to unlock the double moon physics without entering a cheat?

Comment: If there is a way, I haven't found it in my research.

Comment: I haven't tried your cheat, but the missing item in the cheat list wasn't Double Moon Physics – it was Disco Mode (all pipes, rails etc change their color wildly). It was unlocked after I finished Private Carrera's career.